# Swift 3 TableView cellForRowAt with array of custom class

Tags: swift

In another SO post I got help creating a custom class and storing it inside an array.

Now I am trying to populate my tableView with the contents of this array.

so when I try to do

```
let row = indexPath.row

cell.nicknameLabel.text = cardArray[row]
```

It won't work, and I didn't expect it to. I need to somehow say..go into the cardArray then for each class inside the array pull our the variable named nickname/

ive tried

```
cell.niknameLabel.text = cardArray.nickname[row]
```

and

```
...cardArray.CardClass.nickname...
```

But it just gives me different errors

I thought to try to do a for loop into the array
so I did

```
    for item in cardArray {

  cell.cardNicknameLabel.text = item.nickname
  cell.cardTypeLabel.text = item.type

}
```

And while I was able to run this it just gave me one of the classes in the array. I tried to add the [row] to the end of each and I tried after the cardArray on the top part of the for loop but I get an error for everything I try

Any ideas?

Comment: `cell.nicknameLabel.text = cardArray[row].nickname`?  You might want to provide more context into how your structures are set up and how you are dequeue the cell, it'd help

Comment: @MadProgrammer if you want to put that as an answer I will mark it correct. I didn't think I could put anything after the [...] ..but it worked like a charm

Comment: Someone else bet me to it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not use `cell.niknameLabel.text = cardArray.nickname[row]`

instead you should use `cell.niknameLabel.text = cardArray[indexPath.row].nickname`